# How do I get full resolution on my Apple 30" Cinema Display with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, apple

I recently was given a 30" Apple Cinema Display and I am unable to use any resolution other than 1200x800. My computer is a Desktop with an ASUS Strix AMD RX480 and an AMD Ryzen 1800x.

I have attempted using the DVI connection on the graphics card directly into the monitor as well as an HDMI adapter in between. I also updated and try logging in via Wayland or Classic.

Here is my `lspci -nn`

```
⇒  lspci -nn                  
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex [1022:1450]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit [1022:1451]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
00:01.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:03.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:07.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:07.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:1454]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:1454]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0 [1022:1460]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1 [1022:1461]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2 [1022:1462]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3 [1022:1463]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4 [1022:1464]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5 [1022:1465]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric Device 18h Function 6 [1022:1466]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7 [1022:1467]
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961 [144d:a804]
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43b9] (rev 02)
03:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43b5] (rev 02)
03:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43b0] (rev 02)
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
04:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
04:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
04:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
04:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
04:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
04:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] [1002:67df] (rev c7)
0c:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580] [1002:aaf0]
11:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:145a]
11:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:1456]
11:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller [1022:145c]
12:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1455]
12:00.2 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 51)
12:00.3 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:1457]
```

Comment: Not sure how to do it with Wayland but login with Xorg ("classic") and run `xrandr --verbose` to see all possible resolutions and other details.

Comment: have you tried updating the drivers?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte How would I go about finding what drivers I need?

Comment: @Peter Can you add output of `xrandr` with the display connected?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that xorg does not like the other resolution from the display's EDID, have you checked your xorg.0.log when I checked mine I found that the modeline for the full resolution was being rejected.

You can add it back manually using xrandr and and you can make the change persistent using the .xprofile for each account.

You would do that by reading the EDID section from your xorg.0.log file mine looks like this:

```
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: APP  Model: 9221  Serial#: 33558015
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2007  Week: 17
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 64  vert.: 40
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing not preferred mode in violation of standard!
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.343   greenX: 0.292 greenY: 0.611
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.146 blueY: 0.074   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): clock: 71.0 MHz   Image Size:  641 x 401 mm
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1328  h_sync_end 1360 h_blank_end 1440 h_border: 0
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 800  v_sync: 803  v_sync_end 809 v_blanking: 823 v_border: 0
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): clock: 268.0 MHz   Image Size:  641 x 401 mm
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 1600  v_sync: 1603  v_sync_end 1609 v_blanking: 1646 v_border: 0
[  1605.612] (II) modeset(0): Serial No: CY71733DXMP
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0): Monitor name: Cinema HD
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff0006102192ff0d0002
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   111101038040287828fe85a3574a9c25
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   13505400000001010101010101010101
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   010101010101bc1b00a0502017303020
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   360081912100001ab06800a0a0402e60
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   3020360081912100001a000000ff0043
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   59373137333344584d500a00000000fc
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   0043696e656d612048440a0000000155
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   40010300000000c84801a500a5000102
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   031919a8000000000000400000000000
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000000
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000000
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000000
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000000
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000000
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000041
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output DP-1
[  1605.613] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.9   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
```

and you can try out the modeline by opening a terminal and typing in:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1600"  268.00  2560 2608 2640 2720 1600 1603 1609 1646 -hsync +vsync
```

and then change the output to the new mode with:

```
xrandr --addmode DISPLAY_ID 2560x1600
xrandr --output DISPLAY_ID --mode 2560x1600
```

where "DISPLAY_ID" is the display connection name from xrandr's output such as "HDMI-1"

Set up your .xprofile by making a text file named ".xprofile" in each user's home directory and adding these lines:

```
#! /bin/sh

xrandr --newmode "2560x1600"  268.00  2560 2608 2640 2720 1600 1603 1609 1646 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DISPLAY_ID 2560x1600
xrandr --output DISPLAY_ID --mode 2560x1600
```

replacing "DISPLAY_ID" with the display connection name as with the test.

Note: I noticed that this question is a few years old halfway through writing this, but I figure I'll go ahead and post the answer because I sure would like to have found it when I was having this problem.